# How can I farm experience?

Tags: torchlight-2

I do not meet the recommended level for any of the areas that currently contain quest locations. I could probably take the challenge there anyway, but I am curious how I would go about gaining enough experience to get to the recommended levels if I had a mind to.

Is there any way to go back through areas you've already cleared out and kill the enemies there again? Is there some way to reset the area I just cleared so that the enemies respawn there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start a LAN game, check the 'Reroll world' box. All the enemies will be respawmed (possibly allowing you to spawn side quests that didn't appear in the original world - I haven't cared to check for that yet). You'll lose your character's original world. but you'll have tons more mobs to kill. It's kinda boring, tbqh - that level jump isn't as hard as you might think, and the only real annoyance I've had is that items don't drop ID'd anymore because they're higher level than I am. Playing on Normal - my Veteran character got devoured and spat back out trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Doing dungeons under requred level is best way to gain huge chunks of experience.

Thats also main reason why to play your future heroes at highest dificulty :)

Also you can recreate ACTs and replenish them full with enemies once you reach ACT II and futher. You just need to travel from one city to another to refresh them and many repeatable side quests. [This will grant XP only 1st time though, granting FAME instead if repeated]

Answer (score 1):

Start a game in LAN or (private) Internet Multiplayer. There you will have an option to reroll the world which respawns all enemies and recreates all maps. This way you can farm bosses and/or trashmobs.

Answer (score 0):

I just reached the beginning of Act two. In the Ossean Wastes, you will find Dune Mothers. They spawn little scarabs, and as long as you don't kill the Dune Mother, she will continue spawning the scarabs indefinitely as far as I can tell. The problem is that the Dune Mother is super fragile. I tried taking her down to half health, traveling to the previous town and back, but she still maintained the same half health level I left her with. So, the strategy is to place your pet on passive so it doesn't attack the dune mother (keep it passive the entire time to minimize risk of the dune mother coming near and accidentally be hit by your pet), run near the dune mother to trigger her summon of scarabs, and lead the scarabs away from her. I personally use the Prismatic Bolts because it's pretty powerful, has quick casting/recharge time, and strikes multiple opponents at once, which is important because the further you run from the dune mother, and quicker you outpace the scarabs, the more that will turn back towards the dune mother. Prismatic bolts will help engage large numbers at the same time, and damaging them aggro's them, insuring they continue to pursue and assault you.