# Which quests can be repeated?

Tags: torchlight-2

I have finished the game with Veteran difficulty and now I am trying to do the same but with the **Hardcore** option enabled.

The problem is that I am a bit under-leveled and bad equipped and I would like to farm a bit before going on with the main quest. Unfortunately I have cleaned all maps and finished all side-quest, what can I do now?

A friend told me that there are some repeatable quest, is it true? Do you have a list of which are the repeatable quests in Torchlight 2?

Comment: Related to farming, not just about repeatable quests: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85445/how-can-i-farm-experience?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, all side quests are repeatable, if you reroll the world:

- Start a LAN (or Internet) game
- Check "Reroll world"

The other possibility is to buy maps from the "after the last boss" room, which are matching your level.

Comment: Is it possible to reroll a world also when I play Hardcore? Last options that regards the maps is not feasible at the moment because I am still at Act I.

Comment: @Drake - I haven't played hardcore yet, I will have to check.

Comment: Yes you can reroll in Hardcore.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the game keeps only one instance of a dungeon and, I think, one instance of a world map in memory. Once you enter a different dungeon, the previous ones are reset. While quests are not, monsters have respawned. This could help farm some XP.